# How to create a new Category from Console Command

Tags: magento, exception, command, magento2

I'm trying to generate some categories programatically from a Console Command on Magento 2, but Magento responds with this error as soon as the command is executed:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]                          
Class Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryExtensionInterface does not exist
```

The Interface referenced by the error exists on Magento. 
The code to reproduce the error is pretty simple

```
class MyCommand extends Command {

[...initialization block...]

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::class);
}
```

Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: Can you please check file permissions for `var/generation`?

Comment: You where right, I regenerated all permissions on the system as stated here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html and now it works

Comment: Glad to hear it is working. Have posted this as an answer, so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check file permissions for `var/generation`.